# Magento 2: get Nextpage, Lastpage Url in list.phtml file

Tags: magento2, toolbar, list.phtml, pager

How to get Next page, Last Page url in magento 2?

I have try in template file with below codes,

```
   <?php
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
$_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
?>
<?php if (!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><div><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('We can\'t find products matching the selection.') ?></div></div>
<?php else: ?>
    <?php echo $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $block->getAdditionalHtml() ?>
    <?php
        $viewMode = 'grid';
        $image = 'category_page_grid';
        $showDescription = false;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;

    $pos = $block->getPositioned();
    ?>
    <?php //echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Manadev\LayeredNavigation\Blocks\Navigation")->setTemplate("Manadev_LayeredNavigation::navigation.phtml")->toHtml();
        $pagerBlock = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager");
       echo $pagerBlock->getLastPageNum().' test';exit;


        echo $pagerBlock->getNextPageUrl().' sssss';exit;
```

**How to get next and last page url in magento 2 custom template file.
only getting current page url.**

Is there missing for override pager block?

I have to pass nextpage url value inside my custom code.
Also how to check how many page for current category listing?

Any help would be appericiated.

Answer (score 2):

The right methods are `getPreviousPageUrl()` and `getNextPageUrl()`:

```
public function getPreviousPageUrl()
{
    return $this->getPageUrl($this->getCollection()->getCurPage(-1));
}

public function getNextPageUrl()
{
    return $this->getPageUrl($this->getCollection()->getCurPage(+1));
}
```

However, in your case I'm pretty sure it won't help because **you don't assign any collection to your pager.**

I suggest you have a look at how it is done on the product list toolbar:

```
        $pagerBlock->setAvailableLimit($this->getAvailableLimit());

        $pagerBlock->setUseContainer(
            false
        )->setShowPerPage(
            false
        )->setShowAmounts(
            false
        )->setFrameLength(
            $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                'design/pagination/pagination_frame',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            )
        )->setJump(
            $this->_scopeConfig->getValue(
                'design/pagination/pagination_frame_skip',
                \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
            )
        )->setLimit(
            $this->getLimit()
        )->setCollection(
            $this->getCollection()
        );
```

Comment: its not possible to get next and last page url in list page?

Comment: @Rakesh what do you mean ? I didn't say it was not possible I said you were missing the part of the code where you should have assigned the collection to your pager

Comment: plz give me suggestion how to add collection in list.phtml file?

Comment: @Rakesh I posted the code already!!!!

Comment: plz check updated code and i have echo for nextpage url but not getting

Comment: any clue for this answer?